# select_ reorders columns incorrectly

Tags: r, dplyr

This issue just seems to have arisen recently. Say I have the following data frame:

```
tst <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 31:40, d = 41:50, e = 51:60)
```

And I want to select some columns using `select_` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
others <- c("c", "d")
tst %>% select_("a", "b",.dots = others)
```

(Of course, this isn't the best approach in this case, but this is a toy example to demonstrate the issue.) I get the following results:

```
    c  d  a  b
1  31 41  1 11
2  32 42  2 12
3  33 43  3 13
4  34 44  4 14
5  35 45  5 15
6  36 46  6 16
7  37 47  7 17
8  38 48  8 18
9  39 49  9 19
10 40 50 10 20
```

Now, previously – presumably before I updated packages – my columns were ordered a, b, C, d, which makes sense to me since this is the order I select them in. Can anyone else reproduce this? Why does it behave like this?

## Session info:

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
  Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         tools_3.3.3      glue_1.1.0       tibble_1.3.3     Rcpp_0.12.11    
[8] rlang_0.1.1
```

Comment: You should consider upgrading your version of R. I don't know if it's the cause of this problem, but you'll probably encounter other issues when you're behind by a major release.

Comment: I can't. Updates are controlled by my employer.

Comment: `tst %>% select(c('a', 'b', others) )` works for me

Comment: Does it work correctly when using `select_`?

Comment: Your code is giving the same output as you showed

Comment: And, in your opinion, is that incorrect behaviour?

Comment: My guess is this is an order-of-evaluation issue. That is not *unusual* per se

Comment: Okay. Well, thanks for the workaround.

Comment: The easiest workaround is to simply include `a` and `b` to `others`...`others <- c("a","b","c", "d")`

Comment: Great, thanks for your comments

Comment: The commands that end in underscore have been deprecated in dplyr in favour of rlang.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza this is not a major release change, just a minor release (the next major release change will be R-4.0.0).